Snowflake Dynamic Tables dbt core
I am having trouble refreshing Dynamic Tables in Snowflake using dbt core .
My dbt core versions are as follows
Core:

installed: 1.8.3
snowflake: 1.8.3 - Up to date!
This is my dbt_project.yml

      +schema: l10_staging
      +materialized: dynamic_table
      +on_configuration_change: apply
      +target_lag: downstream
      +snowflake_warehouse: compute_wh

DBT build creates the dbt models as Dynamic Tables but a dbt run does not refresh the Dynamic Table but instead generates this command in /target/run/ folder
        alter dynamic table "EDW_DB"."L10_STAGING"."MARA" set
            target_lag = 'downstream'
            warehouse = compute_wh

instead I would on a dbt run evoke to refresh the dynamic table.
        alter dynamic table "EDW_DB"."L10_STAGING"."MARA" REFRESH

Any pointers .
